# StatET debugging tool

Tags: eclipse, debugging, r

I think I'm just being dense, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the debugging tool while working in R in Eclipse (StatET plugin). Has anyone got any tips or tutorials on the subject?

Comment: I'm a StatEt user, but I'm not aware of a debugger built into Statet.  Do you mean the debugging tools built into core R or some other aspect ?

Comment: The debugging tool is part of the Eclipse, I think (Window -> Open Perspective -> Debug), and not built into StatET per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debug framework in Eclipse is not setup to work with R.

Roman Francois had considered having someone code up an integrated debugger that could possibly integrate with Eclipse/Stat-et, but I'm not sure that project progressed.

http://www.r-project.org/soc09/ideas.html#p5

The only "traditional" debugger that I know of that works with R is Revolution's IDE,

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/rpe-the-r-productivity-environment-for-windows.html

That said, I would love to have a debugger for the Stat-et plugin too.

Answer (score 13):

StatET 2.00+ now has experimental support for advanced/visual debugging.  It requires Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7

Installation instructions are [here](http://www.walware.de/?page=/it/downloads/statet.mframe)

You can see a snippet of video from UseR! 2011 [here](http://vimeo.com/27901400)

EDIT:  StatET 2.0.0 released or later includes the integrated debugger and is available [here](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet)

Comment: A minor setback is that R needs to be patched for this.

Comment: It will work without patching R, but you are correct that for full functionality, a patch is required.  Hopefully R-core will incorporate this or equivalent functionality into the core.

Comment: Also, for those interested in testing StatET 3.0, see here: http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2012-May/001408.html

Answer (score 3):

using [StatET 3.3:](http://www.walware.de/it/statet/installation.mframe)

1. Start RConsole as debug (while beeing in the StatET perspective)
   [image]
2. Add breakpoints (by double clicking left to the line) and use `Run Entire Command in R` in the first line of a function definition:
   [image]
3. Run the function. Execution will Break at the Breakpoint and you can inspect local variables by just hovering:

   [image]

---

Very useful, but the bugs? that it doesn't work with `source()` and that `jump into` doesn't work are very annoying as well. Perhaps an earlier version works better.

Comment: Is it possible to use this tool when R code is invoked from Java?